# Why is new able to create an array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, stl

I have seen code that uses arrays of strings in the following way.

```
string *pointer = new string[runtimeAmmount];
```

I have also seen the individual characters in a string accessed as follows.

```
string aString = "this";
char bString[] = "that";
bString[3] = aString[3];
```

The above would result in bString equaling "thas". This would suggest that a string is actually a pointer to the location of the first character. However a string still has member functions accessed as "string.c_str()" meaning it itself as an object does not follow the rules of a pointer. How does this all work?

Note: My original question was to be different but I figures it out typing it out. If someone could still answer my original question just for verification I would appreciate it. My original question is as follows:
How can an array of strings be new'd if each string can vary in length throughout its lifetime? Wouldn't the strings run into each other?

The answer I came up with is:
Strings contain pointers to C-style arrays in some way and so the objects take up a set amount of space.

OR

Strings are something of the STL template variety which I have yet to actually take the time to look at.

Comment: It's called operator overloading.

Comment: You can do that with dereferencing? I was unaware of that.

Comment: I think of `string` as some sort of encapsulation that abstract away the dirty resizing operations while providing a similar interface as C string (char array) with operator overloading of `[]`.

Comment: Yep, you can overload just about everything in C++.  Can confuse the heck out of yourself doing it, and trying to figure out what's legal and why you're getting that stupid error message, but it's quite powerful.

Comment: That would explain a lot. Couldn't figure out how in the world string could both be at its own memory address yet also store a c-style array there. I suppose it is useful though with the problem that it appears to defy logic. Hmm it also appears as though I cannot up-vote comments...

Comment: @user1497468: Yes, although it's not "dereferencing" anymore -- there is no such thing as `*(aString + 3)`, and even if there were, it could behave completely differently. :) I guess I should mention that you will sooner or later see that C++ is a **completely** different beast from C. If you try to do C-style programming in C++, things will be a lot more confusing. Treat it as a new language.

Comment: "*The above would result in bString equaling "that".*" No, it would be equal to `thas`...

Comment: Ahh sorry about that. I swear I wrote "thas" the first time. Thanks for the catch! Also I did not come from C however I have always preferred doing everything myself and so I used c-style strings for a lot of things. Lots to learn about C++ though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will address what is happening in each of the 4 lines of code in your question, but first I should say that your conclusion is not accurate.  You are being "fooled" by the operator overloading built into the `string` class.  While it is likely that *internally*, the `string` class maintains a C-style character array, this is encapsulated and `string` is and should be treated as an opaque object, different from a C-style string.

Now for each of your lines:

```
string *pointer = new string[runtimeAmmount];
```

In this line, `pointer` is set to point to a newly-allocated array of (empty) `string` *objects*.  `runtimeAmmount` is the number of strings in the array, not the number of characters in a C-style string.

```
string aString = "this";
```

This line constructs a new, empty string using the (non-explicit) conversion constructor from the `string` class:  `string(const char *)`.  (Note that in a non-construction context, such as `aString = "this";`, the `operator=(const char *)` overload of the `string` class would be used.)

```
char bString[] = "that";
```

This is a typical C-string being treated as an array of characters.

```
bString[3] = aString[3];
```

This uses the overloaded `operator[]` of the `string` class to return a character (reference) and then assign it to the 3rd character spot in the C-style character array.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks. Very good and thorough explanation. Will upvote when I get my 15 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this:

```
string *pointer = new string[runtimeAmmount];
```

you are creating an array of `string` objects.  Each is constructed with the `string::string` constructor, which can do anything it needs to do.  In this case, the `string` has a pointer to memory which is initialized in the constructor.  So your array is like an array of char* pointers, each of which is malloced individually.

Comment: Many thanks. Will up-vote when I receive 15 rep. Only reason I picked another answer is because it was a little more in depth. Your help is however very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is correct.

A string in C++ is an object, and can contain a pointer to some other storage.
(They need not; google "small string optimization" if you want to see why not - but that's a diversion.)

If you think of a string as a struct that looks like this:

```
struct str {
   int len; // number of bytes allocated
   char *data; // pointer to the data
};
```

then you will be able to see how a string might work.
Note that std::string is actually much more complicated than this; but this should get the idea across.

As for the templates, `std::string` is an instantiation of `std::basic_string`, specialized for `char` (as opposed to `std::wstring`, which is specialized for `wchar_t`)

Comment: Many thanks. Will up-vote when I receive 15 rep. Only reason I picked another answer is because it was a little more in depth. Your help is however very much appreciated. (Yes I copy and pasted but that does not mean I liked your answer less. The other answer was first :P)

Comment: `std::wasting`: now that's an interesting lapsus :D